# Kali-linux & backtrack, text mode and wifi scanning

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, backtrack

As far as i know, when backtrack starts it boots on text mode and the wifi(wlan0) is down in order to be more stealth. Kali linux is the "update" of backtrack and when I boot it always starts in GUI mode. Is it possible to start it in text mode?

Also i noticed that it asks for a wifi connection, so i suppose that the stealth of wifi scanning is not valid anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jan, you give me some clues. I added an answer because i wanted to give the full/good tutorial/explanation.

So, the GRUB must be edited by pressing "tab" and adding for example the run level 2. this is done by adding 2

Kali runlevel 2 still having the internet and the GUI. This can be easily modified with the following tutorial:
http://santhecoder.blogspot.fr/2013/07/boot-kali-linux-in-console-mode-command.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either use runlevel 3 (Multi-user mode without graphical interface) or runlevel 2 (Multi-user modes without networking).

In GRUB, press `a` to change the kernel commandline and add `<space><runlevel>` at the end of the boot options line to boot to the desired runlevel.